# Symfony2 WebTest Request is failing

Tags: symfony, functional-testing

I have this functional test which is failing, giving not found, although when trying out in the browser, it works. I'm guessing it has to do with timing. Is it possible??

```
public function testCreateGet()
{
    $client = static::createClient();
    $client2 = static::createClient();

    $client->request('GET', '/user/create/Juan Lopez/1234.json');
    $id = $client->getResponse()->getContent();
    // e.g. $id = 1

    $client2->request('GET', '/user/getById/'.$id.'.json');
    $clientData = json_decode($client2->getResponse()->getContent());
    // Getting not found here

    $this->assertEquals("Juan Lopez", $clientData['name']);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I hadn't noticed the json format in the user creation response. Updated code, working:

```
$client = static::createClient();

$client->request('GET', '/user/create/Juan Lopez/1234.json');
$response = json_decode($client->getResponse()->getContent());
$id = $response->id;

$client->request('GET', '/user/getById/'.$id.'.json');
$clientData = json_decode($client->getResponse()->getContent());

$this->assertEquals("Juan Lopez", $clientData->name);
```